# Angular Material Datepicker set min programmatically

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to set the min value of the second datepicker if i change the first datepicker, but i can't make it:

I got these two datepicker

```
<mat-form-field>
        <span *ngIf="item.type=='date' && item.hijoDate">
            <input matInput [id]="item.key" [matDatepicker]="picker"
            [min]="minDatePadre" [max]="maxDatePadre"
            (dateChange)="seleccionaFecha($event, 'padre', item.hijoDate)" 
            readonly [placeholder]="item.label" [formControlName]="item.key">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="item.type=='date' && item.padreDate">
              <input matInput [id]="item.key" [matDatepicker]="picker1"
              [min]="minDateHijo" [max]="maxDateHijo" 
              (dateChange)="seleccionaFecha($event, 'hijo', item.padreDate)"
              readonly [placeholder]="item.label" [formControlName]="item.key">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
            </span>
</mat-form-field>
```

In the component i have the following:

```
minDatePadre= new Date(2010, 1, 1);
maxDatePadre= new Date(2020, 0, 1);
minDateHijo= new Date(2010, 1, 1);
maxDateHijo= new Date(2020, 0, 1);
```

I initialize the values, that works perfect and show the max and min in every datepicker, but when i try to change the values it's not working here:

```
seleccionaFecha(event, tipo, elemento){


    if(tipo == 'padre'){
      let fechaHijo = this.form.controls[elemento].value;
      let fechaPadre = event.value;
      if(fechaPadre>fechaHijo){//SI LA FECHA INICIAL ES IGUAL 
        this.form.controls[elemento].setValue(fechaPadre);        
      }

      this.minDateHijo=new Date(2019, 1, 23);      
    }
    else if(tipo == 'hijo'){
      let fechaPadre = this.form.controls[elemento].value;
      let fechaHijo = event.value;


    }


  }
```

when it match the condition i change the value of

```
this.minDateHijo
```

but is not changing nothing and doesn't show any error, i don't know how to update that value, please any help, thank's

**UPDATE: The behavior i can see is that the min value is updated, but the datepicker doesn't until i select some value in the child datepicker then it refreshes, i need to find a way to update the datepicker min value on the go.**

**UPDATE:** this is the stackblitz url with the example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szjuq1

what i want is to choose first datepicker and then set the min date in the second datepicker, but when i choose the first datepicker it only updates him not the next, because i create it dynamically, thanks if you can tell me some way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

When looking at the source code, we can see that the [MatDatepickerInput](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/datepicker/datepicker-input.ts) does not implement the `OnChanges` lifecycle hook, and that the `min` `@Input` is mapped to a getter, that calls the `this._validatorOnChange`, but that function is set to `() => {}`.

Then, the behavior you observe is normal, this control is not designed to dynamically change the `min` value. I suggest you open an issue on GitHub if you want that feature added.

**EDIT:**

The feature request has been submitted and the fix has been committed on the master branch so it should be available in latest releases: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19907

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I got the same problem and I managed to make it work like this

basically you need to dectect changes since Angular Components uses `OnPush`

> dynamic-form-question.component

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

import { QuestionBase } from "./question-base";
const addDays = (date, days) => {
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
};
@Component({
  selector: "app-question",
  templateUrl: "./dynamic-form-question.component.html"
})
export class DynamicFormQuestionComponent {
  @Input() question: QuestionBase<any>;
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  minDate1 = new Date();
  minDate2 = new Date();
  get isValid() {
    return this.form.controls[this.question.key].valid;
  }

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {} // <-- Change DETECTION

  cambio() {
    this.minDate1 = addDays(this.minDate1, 6);
    this.minDate2 = addDays(this.minDate2, 8);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();// <-- Change DETECTION
  }
}
```

here the working stackblitz  [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4smz3m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-form-question.component.ts)